# What is leakage current in an LED?

Tags: led, semiconductors

Is 'carrier leakage from the active region' of an LED the same as 'reverse leakage current'? If they're different what are their respective physical origins?

Comment: Basic diode physics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation)

Comment: @JImDearden They are the same then?

Comment: A diode is a diode is a diode.

Comment: @JImDearden Apologies if it feels like I'm labouring the point. I realise that the page applies to LEDs as it is a diode. But it didn't use the specific terms I'm looking for, and since I have no prior knowledge, I can't look at it and decide whether when they're talking about reverse saturation that's the same as reverse leakage which is the same as carrier leakage from the active region. So is reverse leakage the same as carrier leakage from the active region? I've been trying to find the answer in Schubert's LED book, with no luck I'm afraid!

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294380/2451

Comment: "Carrier leakage" sounds like an all-inclusive term that may add to the Shockley diode equation the current caused by photons. The Shockley equation includes thermal effects, not photon effects. Just a guess.

Comment: @JImDearden "A diode is a diode is a diode". Maybe 20 years ago. Today's LEDs are more than a pn junction. They are heterostructures with quantum wells, electron blocking layer,  with several leakage mechanisms whose relative importance does not seem to see hunanimous agreement (See for example this discussion on the causes of droop: https://www.compoundsemiconductor.net/article/94692-led-droop-a-critical-review-and-novel-solution.html) . They go beyond the Shockley diode equation.

Comment: @SredniVashtar If we get into specifics of OLEDs perhaps but the OP  was asking about an LED. (quite a different animal) **I was simply making a general comment** about looking at the basic physics of a PN junction. From there you can start to build up a picture of different mechanisms which may be significant within a device such as the role of photons, tunnelling, crystal dislocation, ionisation due to radiation  etc.  It was a comment not an answer.

Comment: @JImDearden, I was not talking about Organic LEDs, just the new kind of high efficiency LEDs that are around now. You know, the ones mentioned in the 2014 Nobel Prize in physics. The leakage mechanisms are more elaborate than those found in 'older' LEDs, the one of the GaAs generation (to which "a diode is a diode is a diode" applies). The article I linked gives an overview. For further info one can have a look at the books by Schubert (mentioned by the OP) and Ghione. I added my comment because readers might think that modern LEDs are "just pn junctions" and that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term leakage is applied to reverse biased diodes because ideally the current would be zero.  Saturation means more input doesn't cause a change.  So the leakage current is also referred to as saturation current because it is fairly independent of the amount of reverse bias.  It is not, however, independent of carriers generated by other sources of energy.  If the diode is heated or light is shined on it, more carriers will be freed up to contribute increasing the reverse saturation current.  The limit of leakage current has to do with the limited number of minority carries near the junction.